# How to store global variable names in local variables in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, global

So I am trying to create a function that will let me simply call the function, and I give it 10 values, and a variable, and it will change that variable into one of the values provided, randomly.

```
import random

place = "NA"

def randomize (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8, value9, value10, variable):
global variable
variable  = random.choice([value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8, value9, value10])

randomize ("Dungeon", "Plains", "Castle", "Prison", "Tavern", "Armory", "Docks", "Warehouse", "ThroneRoom", "Bedroom", place)

print place
```

This however tells me the following:

```
SyntaxError: name 'variable' is local and global
```

Comment: Well why do you pass `variable` as **a parameter** and mark it as **global** in the same method?

Comment: Because the variable that I am trying to change is global. But the function will be used to change different variables, so I have to tell the function which variable to change.

Comment: `global` does not work that way, you pass global the **identifier**, so it will **always** change a variable with the name `variable`...

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal,Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Well is there a way to make this work, or should I just not do it as a function?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you don't usually modify input parameters. I know this is standard in C, but it's easier to return the value and assign you variable to the output of the function instead:

```
import random

def randomize(*values):
    return random.choice(values)

place = "NA"
print place

place = randomize("Dungeon", "Plains", "Castle", "Prison", "Tavern", "Armory", "Docks", "Warehouse", "ThroneRoom", "Bedroom")
print place
```

Answer (score 0):

For `1, 2, 3, ... n` values you should use a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#list). You also need to write less code, so it scales better. And you should try to avoid [global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765560/avoid-using-global-without-confusing-new-programming-students-in-python)... Reasons why you can find [in the global internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil). For this example you even could save a method definition.

```
import random
places = ["Dungeon", "Plains", "Castle", "Prison", "Tavern", "Armory", "Docks",
          "Warehouse", "ThroneRoom", "Bedroom"]  # list with n elements...
place = random.choice(places)
print place
```